# CSS extends beyond max-width

Tags: css

I've set the max-width here on two locations but the table continues to extend far beyond these values.  What am I doing wrong?

Sample CSS:

```
    #WADAPageTitleArea {
    /* width: 555px; */
}
#WADAPageTitleArea div, #WADAPageTitleArea p {
    font-size: 11px;
    padding-bottom: 7px;
}
#WADAPageTitleArea div#WADAPageTitle, #WADAPageTitle {
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.WADAResults, .WADANoResults {
    border-top: 1px solid #AEBBC2;max-width:300px !important;
}
.WADAResultsNavigation {
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}
.WADAResultsCount {
    font-size: 11px;
}
.WADAResultsNavTop, .WADAResultsInsertButton {
    clear: none;
}
.WADAResultsNavTop {
    width: 60%;
    float: left;
}
.WADAResultsInsertButton {
    width: 30%;
    float: right;
    text-align: right;
}
.WADAResultsNavButtonCell, .WADAResultsInsertButton {
  padding: 2px;
}
.WADAResultsTable {
    font-size: 11px;
    clear: both;
    padding-top: 1px;
    padding-bottom: 1px;
    max-width:300px !important;
}

.WADAResultsTableHeader, .WADAResultsTableCell {
  padding-right: 7px;
  padding-left: 7px;
    text-align: left;
}

.WADAResultsTableHeader {
    padding-left: 14px;
    padding-right: 14px;
}

.WADAResultsTableCell {
    padding-left: 7px;
    padding-right: 7px;
}

.WADAResultsTableCell {
  border-left: 1px solid #AEBBC2;
}

.WADAResultsEditButtons {
  border-left: 1px solid #AEBBC2;
  border-right: 1px solid #AEBBC2;
}

.WADAResultsRowDark {
  background-color: #DCE4ED;
}
```

Table Code:

```
 <table class="WADAResultsTable" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
          <tr>
            <th class="WADAResultsTableHeader" style="">Species:</th>
          </tr>
          <?php do { ?>
            <tr class="<?php echo $WARRT_AltClass1->getClass(true); ?>">
              <td class="WADAResultsTableCell" style="word-wrap:break-word"><strong><?php echo($row_WADAFL_Regs['Species']); ?></strong><br /><img style=" " src="/tides/florida-fish/images/<?php echo($row_WADAFL_Regs['Photo']); ?>" /><HR />
              Minimum Size Limits: <?php echo($row_WADAFL_Regs['Minimum_Size_Limits']); ?><BR />
              Closed Season: <?php echo($row_WADAFL_Regs['Closed_Season']); ?><BR />
              Daily Rec Bag Limit: <?php echo($row_WADAFL_Regs['Daily_Rec_Bag_Limit']); ?><BR />
              Remarks: <?php echo($row_WADAFL_Regs['Remarks']); ?></td>
            </tr>
          <?php } while ($row_WADAFL_Regs = mysql_fetch_assoc($WADAFL_Regs)); ?>
        </table>
```

Comment: Please include relevant source code here so the question remains useful after your site is updated, or gets taken offline, etc. See [ask]

Comment: Add `display: block; overflow: hidden;` to your `table` element

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a **Stack Snippet**. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See [**Something in my website doesn't work can I just paste a link**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One work around could be to set an id for the images, and set the max-width for that id, since at the moment, from inspecting the images, it seems that the max-width you have set is overruled

Like so in html:

```
<img id="fish-img" src="image.png">
```

And in css:

```
#fish-img {
  max-width: 300px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `min-width`/`max-width` attributes apply to floating and absolutely positioned block and `inline-block` elements, as well as some intrinsic controls. They do not apply to non-replaced inline elements, such as table rows and row/column groups. (A "replaced" element has intrinsic dimensions, such as an img or textArea.)

You should use `table-layout: fixed;` for the `table` element to get the `max-width` properties of `<td>`'s descendants to work.

```
table {
    table-layout: fixed;
}
```